# What is best way to use node.js and MSMQ?

Tags: node.js, msmq

I need create public queue with Microsoft Message Queuing(MSMQ) and send/receive messages from node.js server. What is best way to use node.js and MSMQ?

I'm interested in the "Fire-and-forget" model.

Comment: Looking to use a message queue in a small web app with node.js and your goal is to push notifications to clients based on backend and other client actions with socketio ?

Comment: @Venkatraman I'm interested in the "Fire-and-forget" pattern

Comment: Hi, I'm looking into similar things right now, did you happen to find a solution?

Comment: @user1491987 Unfortunately, the basic solutions are not found. Only creating wrappers in another technology or using COM-objects =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too have the same use case. Whilst searching I stumbled across the [node-msmq](https://github.com/marcobarcelos/node-msmq) package on NPM/GitHub.

It is relatively new (May 2016) but I have had no issues with it to date. Simple API with a clear usage guide - worth a look.

Answer (score -1):

> Note: I'm not very sure this will be the answer but it helps

Try `BusMQ` is message bus and queueing system for node.js. Message queues are backed by Redis.

Code: https://github.com/capriza/node-busmq

```
var Bus = require('busmq');
var bus = Bus.create({redis: ['redis://127.0.0.1:6379']});
bus.on('online', function() {
  var q = bus.queue('foo');
  q.on('attached', function() {
    console.log('attached to queue');
  });
  q.attach();
  q.push({hello: 'world'});
  q.push('my name if foo');
});
bus.connect();
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer :) 
I found solutions for nodejs + redis, nodejs + rabbitmq, nodejs + zmq and etc. Unfortunately, my current work project is written using MSMQ :(